# Parallel make: specify order between prerequisites

Tags: makefile

I have the following Makefile:

```
resources: rsrcsubdirs

rsrcsubdirs: rsrcadd $(RSRCSUBDIRS)

$(RSRCSUBDIRS):
        @$(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)

resclean:  $(RSRCSUBDIRS)
        @$(RM) -rf $(BUILD)/resources/
```

$(RSRCSUBDIRS) is a list of folders.
 Before executing make for all of them, the "rsrcadd" executable should be created. It is created by the rule rsrcadd.

The problem is, when running Make in parallel, it seems impossible to tell it, that rsrcsubdirs depends on rsrcadd, but rsrcadd should be executed BEFORE $(RSRCSUBDIRS). It always tries to execute all prerequisites in parallel

Order-only prerequisites:

```
rsrcsubdirs: $(RSRCSUBDIRS) | rsrcadd
```

do not do what I want:

Even multiple levels of targets:

```
resources: rsrcadd rsrcsubdirs

rsrcsubdirs: rsrcadd rsrcsubdirs1      

rsrcsubdirs1: $(RSRCSUBDIRS)
```

do not do what I want.

There is nothing like

```
rsrcsubdirs: $(DO_IT_AFTER(rsrcadd))
```

The only thing that works is:

```
$(RSRCSUBDIRS): rsrcadd
        @$(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

tell $(RSRCSUBDIRS) to depend on rsrcadd.
But this breaks the resclean rule. Make resclean will call rsrcadd before cleaning files.

It looks like I am missing something. Is there elegant way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You *must* add the order-only prerequisite to the `$(RSRCSUBDIRS)` targets, because those are the targets that require it.  Adding it to `rsrcsubdirs` target doesn't help because all that says is that before `rsrcsubdirs` target itself can be built, `rsrcadd` must be complete.  That's not enough as you've seen.

One way to do it would be to check which target you're building and don't add the order-only prerequisite if it's `clean`.  For example:

```
ifeq (clean,$(filter clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
    PREREQ :=
else
    PREREQ := rsrcadd
endif

  ...

$(RSRCSUBDIRS): $(PREREQ)
        @$(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

Now when you run `make clean`, `$(PREREQ)` will be empty otherwise it will be `rsrcadd`.